# Geoserver doesn't render labels

Tags: geoserver, sld, css

I've tried to create several types of GeoServer layer stylings with basic labels, both in SLD and via the GeoServer CSS extension. Yet, not once have I managed to get the labels actually rendered. Everything else renders as it should.

I'm running GeoServer 2.11 on Centos 7 (had the same issue on GS 2.9 as well). Data's coming from PostgreSQL 9.2.15 (64-bit, UTF-8 encoded databases).

For instance trying to create a simple polygon style with attribute-based labels in CSS:

```
* {
  fill: #95C8C1;
  label: [field];
  font-fill: #000000;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 7;
  font-style: normal;
  label-anchor: 0.5 0.5;
}
```

I've checked for all possible field name letter size matches vs. the data, and also non-field based labels, but nothing.

Similar styling in SLD, also does not render labels:

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
<NamedLayer>
<Name>Polygon styling test</Name>
 <UserStyle>
  <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#95C8C1</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
      <TextSymbolizer>
        <Label>
          <ogc:PropertyName>field</ogc:PropertyName>
        </Label>
        <Font>
          <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="font-size">7</CssParameter>
        </Font>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
      </TextSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
   </FeatureTypeStyle>
  </UserStyle>
 </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I've tried fiddling around with GeoServer VendorOptions (ConflictResolution etc.), but those break my stylings completely and layers fail to display. Also enabled/disabled caching, reset options, emptied caches, tried different gutters, etc., but nothing.

The only hint I've encountered so far is in the GeoServer logs:

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR [renderer.label] - Error adding label to the label cache
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any idea on what is the underlying reason for all this? Is Java getting Null values for the label for some reason?

Comment: are you sure you have an attribute called exactly `field` in your layer? check on the layer data page which will show you the attributes

Comment: The field name "field" was here only for illustrative purposes, but yes, I've checked the actual attribute name against the layer data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was finally found, under the hood...

After trying a bunch of different usual suspect fonts, started to wonder why the fc-list command returned no information - there were absolutely no fonts installed on the server!

Since I needed to use a bunch of specific MS fonts, this seemed to do the trick:

```
wget http://www.itzgeek.com/msttcore-fonts-2.0-3.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh msttcore-fonts-2.0-3.noarch.rpm
```

Or a different approach via yum:

```
yum install curl cabextract xorg-x11-font-utils fontconfig
yum install 
https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mscorefonts2/rpms/msttcore-fonts-
installer-2.6-1.noarch.rpm
```